# Why is string not written in destination file using go colly?

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I have a web scraper and I need to write a string from HTML code to my CSV file.
The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="qa-static-ad-map-container">
       <img src="/app/static/media/staticmap.65e20ad98.svg" alt="Bucuresti - Ilfov, Bucuresti, 
         Sectorul 4" class="css-149mw5z">
</div>
```

I have to somehow get the text in the alt attribute; This is the code I've written:

```
c.OnHTML(".qa-static-ad-map-container img", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) { //class that contains wanted info
        writer.Write([]string{
            e.Attr("alt"),
        })
    })
```

It doesn't give any error and also shows me that the onHtml request has been made, but nothing is written in the file.

Comment: Do you see the attribute text, when you use e.g. `fmt.Println`?

Comment: No, apparently not

Comment: If `fmt.Println` doesn't work either, maybe the function isn't called at all.

Comment: I have pretty much the same function for another source of an image and that one works fine

Comment: use `fmt.Println(e)` to already see what you're dealing with. Maybe the selector is wrong?

Comment: I've tried this and it shows nothing

Comment: Can you provide your full program? I'll try to help you then!

Comment: I managed to solve the problem; thanks anyway!